# datalist item template in webpart for  sharepoint list

Tags: asp.net, spgridview

i am looking for some cool stuff / example to work around with ASP DataList ItemTemplate to provide an interesting look and feel !!

well i have a SharePoint (2010) List that has 3 columns (Title , Description,Image) i want to create a visual webpart or an aspx page in VS2010 that fetches information from that List & form a UI as shown :

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/XJSCuzvdV0qwWQgcuCDblw?feat=directlink

can anyone help me out or suggest some blogs/site for the same stuff...

thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with either:

XsltListViewWebParts (superceded the DataViewWebPart in SharePoint 2007) in SharePoint Designer

or

ContentQueryWebParts with a custom ItemStyle.xsl

Google for both, lots of examples out there. No need whatsoever for managed code / visual web parts.